# How can I use this unicode symbol - ⓘ - with Imagick to annotate to an image?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, imagick, utf-16

I'm trying to annotate this unicode symbol ⓘ  (\u24D8) to an image using Imagick .. so far without success ..

I've tried this:

```
$info = new ImagickDraw();
$info->setFontSize(18);
$info->setTextEncoding('UTF-8');
$iSym1 = "ⓘ";
$iSym2 = mb_convert_encoding($iSym1, 'UTF-8', 'GB18030');

$pass = new Imagick();
$pass->newImage($passFrontX, $passFrontY, $passFrontBG);
$pass->setImageFormat('png');
$pass->annotateImage($info, 293, 440, 0, utf8_decode($iSym2));
```

I've tried with & without utf8_decode ..

Any idea if it's possible to annotate such symbols to an image with Imagick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a font that includes that character in it. You don't need to use any of that encoding stuff you've attempted.

I downloaded the font "Arial Unicode MS" and using the code below, I get this image:

[image]

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFontSize(36);
$draw->setTextEncoding('UTF-8');
$draw->setFillColor('white');

$draw->setFont(realpath("./arial-unicode-ms.ttf"));

$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->newImage(300, 150, "blue");
$imagick->setImageFormat('png');
$imagick->annotateImage($draw, 50, 75, 0, "chars: ⓘ⒌⒝");
$imagick->drawImage($draw);
$imagick->writeImage("./fontTest.png");
```

Comment: Excellent! You have the best answers! Best! Making SO great again!